# Ending a called Sub procedure and continuing to the next called Sub procedure

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on a project in which I use a `Validate` sub procedure to validate a set of values within a group of text boxes and then use a second sub procedure `Sum` to add the values of the text boxes together.

Currently when I call in the subs like so:

```
Private Sub SumButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SumButton.Click

    Call ValidateProcedure()
    Call Sum()

End Sub
```

The `ValidateProcedure` doesn't stop if an error is found, the validate procedure works like so:

'Purpose: To make sure all values entered into text boxes 1-4 & the category textbox are valid

```
    Dim Score1Message As String
    Dim Score2Message As String
    Dim Score3Message As String
    Dim Score4Message As String
    Dim CategoryMessage As String

    'TextBox1 Validation
    If Score1TextBox.Text = "" Then
        Score1Message = "Score 1 is blank"
    ElseIf Score1TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score1TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        Score1Message = "Score 1 is not in range: 0-10"
    Else
        Score1Message = "Score 1 is valid"
    End If

    'Textbox 2 Validation 
    If Score2TextBox.Text = "" Then
        Score2Message = "Score 2 is blank"
    ElseIf Score2TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score2TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        Score2Message = "Score 2 is not in range: 0-10"
    Else
        Score2Message = "Score 2 is valid"
    End If

    'Score 3 Validation 
    If Score3TextBox.Text = "" Then
        Score3Message = "Score 3 is blank"
    ElseIf Score3TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score3TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        Score3Message = "Score 3 is not in range 0-10"
    Else
        Score3Message = "Score 3 is Valid"
    End If

    'Score 4 validation 
    If Score4TextBox.Text = "" Then
        Score4Message = "Score 4 is blank"
    ElseIf Score4TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score4TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        Score4Message = "Score 4 is not in range: 0-10"

    Else
        Score4Message = "Score 4 is valid"
    End If

    'Category Validation
    If CategoryTextBox.Text = "" Then
        CategoryMessage = "Category is blank"

    ElseIf CategoryTextBox.Text <> "a".ToUpper Or CategoryTextBox.Text <> "b".ToUpper Or CategoryTextBox.Text <> "c".ToUpper Then
        CategoryMessage = "Category is not value A,B or C"
    Else
        CategoryMessage = "Category is valid"
    End If



    'Display validation strings in statusLabel 
    StatusLabel.Text = Score1Message & Environment.NewLine &
        Score2Message & Environment.NewLine &
        Score3Message & Environment.NewLine &
        Score4Message & Environment.NewLine &
        CategoryMessage






End Sub
```

So what I'm trying to do is make it validate the values of the text boxes and if there are no errors then proceed with the `Sum` sub procedure. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Function` which return a Boolean value of validating result:

```
If Validate() = True Then
    Sum()
End If
```

Change your procedure(`Sub`) `ValidateProcedure` to a `Function`

```
Private Function Validate() As Boolean
    'Because you concatenate all your messages together in the end, 
    'then may be better to use StringBuilder
    Dim errormsg as New StringBuilder()

    'TextBox1 Validation
    If Score1TextBox.Text = "" Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 1 is blank")
    ElseIf Score1TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score1TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 1 is not in range: 0-10")
    Else
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 1 is valid")
    End If

    'Textbox 2 Validation 
    If Score2TextBox.Text = "" Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 2 is blank")
    ElseIf Score2TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score2TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 2 is not in range: 0-10")
    Else
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 2 is valid")
    End If

    'Score 3 Validation 
    If Score3TextBox.Text = "" Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 3 is blank")
    ElseIf Score3TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score3TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 3 is not in range 0-10")
    Else
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 3 is Valid")
    End If

    'Score 4 validation 
    If Score4TextBox.Text = "" Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 4 is blank")
    ElseIf Score4TextBox.Text > 10 Or Score4TextBox.Text < 0 Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 4 is not in range: 0-10")
    Else
        errormsg.AppendLine("Score 4 is valid")
    End If

    'Category Validation
    If CategoryTextBox.Text = "" Then
        error.msg.AppendLine("Category is blank")

    ElseIf CategoryTextBox.Text <> "a".ToUpper Or CategoryTextBox.Text <> "b".ToUpper Or CategoryTextBox.Text <> "c".ToUpper Then
        errormsg.AppendLine("Category is not value A,B or C")
    Else
        errormsg.AppendLine("Category is valid")
    End If

    StatusLabel.Text = errormsg.ToString()
    'Then based on the error messages return a Boolean value:
    If errormsg.Length = 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Fabio, 
Sorry I don't quite follow I'm an extremely amateur programmer. 
So I convert the Validate Sub Procedure to a Function? 

I am not too familiar with functions. Such as knowing where to put the return or what variables to include in the parenthesis in this case

Comment: `Function` can be created like a `Sub` without a parameters

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I will work through the code you put up (There are a few things I haven't ran into yet such as Errormsg.appendline and StringBuilder) I don't want to use anything I don't completely understand but once I completely understand these concepts I'll definitely use it thank you! Would there be a way to validate weather it is true or false without using the errormsg.length?

Comment: then just put `return False` on all `if else`, and `return True` in the end of code

Comment: Sorry to be annoying Fabio, but if I put I put return False at the end of all the ElseIf statements then it terminates without delivering the statuslabel.text!

Comment: :) Thats why was created `errormsg` object of `StringBuilder` type. And after all `if else` print error messages (`StatusLabel.Text = errormsg.ToString()`), after that check if error messages object are empty (`if errormsg.Length = 0`). If so then return true

Comment: Haha thanks Fabio, Well I better get very familiar with Stringbuilder and those other functions. Thanks alot for adding to my knowledge ^^  You've been a great help!